# Modify the code by Passing Dataset path, Dataset name and the variable name

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a below code where I am passing just the variable name. But, I want to add the path of the dataset and the dataset name along with the variable name.
Please find the below code:

```
variable = '~!'.join[str(item) for item in inputlist])
task = {'plaintext': variable}
header = {
       'accesstoken' : accesstoken
     }
resp = request.post('http://URL', json=task , headers = header,verify=False)
resTempList = resp.text.split('~!')
return resTempList
```

I would be running the script from the command prompt.  Also., I want to add is that., I want to pass the dataset name, path and the input list from the command line.
(example: script.py C:/data/text datset_name variable_name) Please let me know the required changes to be made.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: N.B. it's either ``` (not ''') for code, or indentation, not both :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code as per your need. added the comments

```
import sys 
variable= " ".join(sys.argv[1:])
task = {'plaintext': variable}
header = {
       'accesstoken' : accesstoken
     }
resp = request.post('http://URL', json=task , headers = header,verify=False)
resTempList = resp.text.split('~!')
return resTempList
```

from the command line run as below :

```
script.py function_name sample.sas7bdat C:\data\ address
```

variable will be of type string and will look like

```
function_name sample.sas7bdat C:\data\ address
```

Comment: thank you for the reply. Can you please tell me how to incorporate this in the above script??

Comment: add variable_name,data_path,dataset_name = sys.argv[1],sys.argv[2],sys.argv[3] at the top of your code. now when you execute the program as mentioned in the comments of the code, you will get the passed arguments in these order variable_name ,data_path, dataset_name. then do whatever operation you need on them

Comment: I get that part. I was able to pass those three variables via command line. The thing is i am new to Python and i am not able to make changes to the existing code. I want to add the three parameters into the above code (currently passing on the the variable_name).

Comment: can you give an example how the variable will look after passing the arguments?

Comment: For example I want to pass: dataset_name = sample.sas7bdat dataset_path = C:\data\example variable_name = address. And I want to execute the above script from the command line in the following way..  >> script.py sample.sas7bdat C:\data\example address

Comment: Yes. But that is how you want to send..it is fine, after executing in the above format you mentioned, how should the variable look like ? For ex : should it be like : variable = sample.sas7bdat c:\data\example address ....or.... Variable = sample.sas7bdat ; c:\data\ example ; address

Comment: without semicolon is fine...

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention is., the script that I have posted is part of a function. And even that function name has to be parameterized and has to be passed on from command line alone with dataset_name, path and the variable. Example: >> script.py function_name sample.sas7bdat C:\data\ address; where script.py is the program name., function_name is the function which is built inside the program., sample.sas7bdat is the dataset name, followed by path and lastly address is the variable name.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. Can you also help me in incorporating your code into mine??? i mean how can i pass the other parameters like dataset name, path. currently inputlist is just variable name

Comment: updated. read the answer to understand how you can pass other parameters like dataset name, path.

Comment: Awesome... One last point is there a way that you can change the script without modifying the existing logic. Because the variable name needs to be passed in that specific way...

Comment: In other words, retain the existing script as is., and add new parameters to it without changing the existing parameter

Comment: yes you can pass extra parameters through command line as mentioned in the answer, it will be available in the variable. sys.argv[1:] means all the parameters passed are fetched. please upvote and accept the answer if it solved your question

Comment: @prad001 Accept and upvote the answer if it worked